# Editing a Wordpress theme on cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

How do I edit the markup of my WordPress theme on cPanel? Do I have to navigate to the .php files of every element on the webpage (header.php, footer.php etc) or is there a .php or .html file with everything in it?

Answer (score 1):

Before editing your wordpress theme, I suggest you to create a child theme, so that your changes won't lose when you update the theme.

To create child theme refer this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Yes, if want to edit header file, the copy header.php from theme folder to child theme folder and make change you want.

Answer (score 1):

First, get FTP program and connect to your server. Using cPanel for this is not the way to go.

Depending on your system you can choose between [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en) etc.

Once you connect to your server go to the installation folder, then to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme`.

You can download as a backup your theme before editing it, or you can create [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and make changes to it. Your choice what you prefer.

If you look at the contents of your theme folder, you'll notice the theme structure. I recommend that you look at [theme development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to get the gist of it. You'll need some knowledge of `php`, `HTML/CSS` and `JavaScript`.